# Unity World Not Showing on GitHub

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I am new to development on Unity. My teammate and I are collaborating on a 3D project and we are using GitHub. He mentioned to me that he is unable to view my world creation from his side when he pulled.

Could someone please assist? Thank you.

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore
#
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
[Ll]ogs/
[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Recordings can get excessive in size
/[Rr]ecordings/

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage
*.app

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

.DS_Store
```

Should I delete any of the lines within my .gitignore file?
Which files would be linked to 3D world creation?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I pulled the most current repo onto my other computer and he is correct, the world I created is not shown.

Comment: Did you open the scene file after loading the project?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Like I explained in my OP. We are beginners with developing on Unity. How do I open the data within the scene? I clicked the file with the Unity logo on a white background with a black border (it says Scene Asset within the inspector) and then clicked "open". My terrain data is not showing nor are other objects within my scene. Could you please write more thoroughly? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your Assets folder and look for a white file with a thick black border and select that. This will open up your scene. You must manually place in your terrain data and then replace missing terrain textures within each layer.